# Airflow web-server produces temporary 502 errors in Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm encountering 502 errors on AirFlow(2.0.2) UI hosted in Cloud Composer(1.17.0).

```
Error: Server Error The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

They last for a few minutes and it happens several times a day after it's gone everything works fine.

At the moment of errors:

- there is a gap in logs and after we can see that logs resumed with messages about staring gunicorn:
  `[1133] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.10.0`
- there is a spike in resource usage of web-server
- I didn't spot any other suspicious activity in other parts of the system(workers, scheduler, DB)

I think that this is a result of **OOM** error because we have DAGs with a big number of tasks (2k).
But I'd like to be sure and I haven't found **a way to connect to VM of app engine in tenant project**(where Airflow server is hosted by default) to get additional logs.

**Maybe anyone knows a way to get additional logs from AirFlow server VMs or have any other idea?**

Comment: So, I'm pretty sure, the issue was in OOM of an app engine. I excluded any other possible reason and reproduced it consistently by loading extended history for DAG with a big number of tasks. The resolution is to update a webserver to VM with bigger memory.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Composer documentation shows [Troubleshooting DAGs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/troubleshooting-dags) sections. It shows how to check individual workers logs. It even mentions OOM issues ([direct link](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/troubleshooting-dags#task-fails-without-logs)).

Generally troubleshooting section is well documented so you should be able to find many interesting information. You can also use Cloud Monitoring and Cloud Logging to monitor Composer, but I am not sure if this will be valuable in this use case ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/monitoring-environments)).

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. But the issue was on a web server that is separate from workers and hosted in an app engine.